# Getting error Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I am getting `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20)` error on this line `[target setAlpha:0.0f];`

When I tried to login my App using fingerprint authentication, my App crashed. When I debug it I found this issue

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x20).
```

Here's my code:

```
- (void)blinkAnimation:(NSString *)animationID finished:(BOOL)finished target:(UIView *)target
{
    NSString *selectedSpeed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"EffectSpeed"];
    float speedFloat = (0.82 - [selectedSpeed floatValue]);

    [UIView beginAnimations:animationID context:(__bridge void *)(target)];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:speedFloat];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(blinkAnimation:finished:target:)];

    if([target alpha] == 1.0f)
        [target setAlpha:0.0f];
    else
        [target setAlpha:1.0f];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Do you have an error log in console?

Comment: check value you got from user defaults and check the view if it is in the view hierarchy or not

Comment: No. This happens after 5 to 10 tries.

Comment: Note enough info here; post the crash report or full set of backtraces.